# The location finder is not working and instead is showing something unusual. Any help? Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a gun that fits all my criteria and it was going well until now. I made a code that every time a player clicks the mouse, It notes the barrel position which is an extra secret part which just is a place to spawn the bullet. Unfortunately, I have to use a local script because the server script will spawn the bullet at the hidden gun where you were working on it. So, I wanted to use a remote event to send info to the server script to spawn the bullet there. But for some reason it says 'VoltyDeElectroDragon 328.80020141602 3.400004863739' instead of '328.80020141602 3.400004863739 -144.67500305176' and I don't know whats wrong. The same problem occured in a different version of my gun. Here's the local script code:

```
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local barrel = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Barrel", 0.00001)
local barrelx = barrel.Position.X
local barrely = barrel.Position.Y
local barrelz = barrel.Position.Z

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
        local HitX = mouse.Hit.X
        local HitY = mouse.Hit.Y
        local HitZ = mouse.Hit.Z
        print(barrelx, barrely, barrelz)
        script.Parent.Fire:FireServer(barrelx, barrely, barrelz)
    end)
end)
```

And here is the Server Script code:

```
local bullet = game.ReplicatedStorage.Bullet
local gunposX = script.Parent.Barrel.Position.X
local gunposY = script.Parent.Barrel.Position.Y
local gunposZ = script.Parent.Barrel.Position.Z

local function Fire(barrelx, barrely, barrelz)
    print(barrelx, barrely, barrelz)
    part.Position = Vector3.new(HitX, HitY, HitZ)
    local bulletcopy = bullet:Clone()
    bulletcopy.Parent = game.Workspace
    bulletcopy.Position = Vector3.new(gunposX, gunposY, gunposZ)
    local Bulletshoot = Instance.new("BodyForce", bulletcopy)
    Bulletshoot.Force = Vector3.new(0, 0, 100)
end

script.Parent.Fire.OnServerEvent:Connect(Fire)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument on a [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent)'s `OnServerEvent` is the [player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) that called `FireServer()`

You need to update the function signature to account for this :

```
local function Fire(player, barrelx, barrely, barrelz)
```